# Compute the area delimited by a curve in implicit form (solution verification)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification, area

I have to compute the are delimited by $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}=\sqrt{a}$ with $a>0$.
My idea is, let for instance $a=1$:
$$\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}=\sqrt{a}\iff |y|=(1-\sqrt{|x|})^2$$ And since $$ |y| =
\begin{cases} y\,\,\, ,if\,\,\, y>0\\ -y\,\,\, ,if\,\,\,  y<0  \end{cases}$$ then $$y=\pm(1-\sqrt{|x|})^2$$
Now the graph of $|y|$ in $[-1,1]$ is given by

[image]

So if I compute the integral from $-1$ to $1$ of $y=(1-\sqrt{|x|})^2$ then multiplying by $2$ I obtain also the area given by the $y=-(1-\sqrt{|x|})^2$ (so the portion of area under $x$ axis). And so $$Area=2\int_{-1}^{1} (1-\sqrt{|x|})^2\, dx=\frac{2}{3}$$
The other two portions of plane (for $x\geq 1$ and $x\leq -1$) is something I have not consider since gives me a divergent integral and so no sense in terms of area).
Is my idea right?

EDIT: I fear that the plot is not right...

Answer (score 1):

Your chart should not extend outside $[-a,a]$ on either axis as $\sqrt{|x|} \ge 0$ and $\sqrt{|y|} \ge 0$ so $\sqrt{|x|} +\sqrt{|y|} \le \sqrt{a} \implies \sqrt{|x|}\le \sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{|y|}\le \sqrt{a}$, and so $|x|\le a$ and $|y|\le a$.  It should also have a quarter-turn rotational symmetry and reflective symmetry across the diagonal line $y=x$, which yours does not. See below for mine

I think there may be an issue in your integral too: is $2\frac13$ equal to $\frac73$ or $\frac23$? An area over $2$ would involve the curves going outwards from a diagonal rather than inwards.  If you just look in the positive quadrant, and then multiply by $4$ for the symmetric quadrants, I think

$$\text{Area } = 4 \int_{0}^a (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})^2\, dx \\ = 4\int_{0}^a (a - 2\sqrt{a}\sqrt{x} +x)\, dx \\ = 4 \left[ax - \frac43\sqrt{a}x^{3/2} +\frac12x^2\right]_0^a \\ = \frac23 a^2$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. one thing: the fact that you write $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}\leq a$ is due to what? I have an equation and so $=$

Comment: @pawel $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|} =\sqrt{a}$ is the boundary of the area while all points on or inside the boundary satisfy $\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|} \le \sqrt{a}$

Comment: Ok very thanks! If you should write the explicit equation for $y$ which is this precisely? I have tried in the other question to do this without success